# Using CSS, is there a way to float multiple DIVs overlapping a sibling DIV?

Tags: html, css

The following code does what I want:

```css
.foo {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.baz {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  float: right;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 15px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.qux {
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 280px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="baz"></div>
    <div class="baz"></div>
    <div class="baz"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="qux"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this without the intervening `bar` div? In other words, can I achieve the same effect (`baz` divs floated right, overlaying the `qux` div) with the following code:

```
    <div class="foo">
      <div class="baz"></div>
      <div class="baz"></div>
      <div class="baz"></div>
      <div class="qux"></div>
    </div>
```

It's a small thing, but I have reasons to keep the HTML as simple as possible in this project.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to do something with CSS-Grid but otherwise positioning is your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.foo {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.baz {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20px;
}

.baz:nth-child(1) {
  right: 15px;
}

.baz:nth-child(2) {
  right: 39px; // 15px + 4px margin + 20px width
}

.baz:nth-child(3) {
  right: 63px; // 39px + 4px margin + 20px width
}

.qux {
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 280px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="baz"></div>
  <div class="baz"></div>
  <div class="baz"></div>
  <div class="qux"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea! I knew I wasn't thinking far enough outside the box. I hadn't thought of nth-child — it fits the bill perfectly.

Comment: @TobyRush Glad i could help :)